# Is it possible to set multiple background color in QChart?

Tags: qt6

Win11 + Qt6.4

I want to set corresponding background color within different x-coordinate range in  QChart, is it possible?

I didn't find way to specify a certain range for QChart::setPlotAreaBackgroundBrush() in QChart.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve (perhaps with code or an image of the desired result) and also explain why [`QChart::setPlotAreaBackgroundBrush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qchart.html#setBackgroundBrush) won't work?  Why not render the desired background to a `QImage` and use that image to create the [`QBrush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbrush.html#QBrush-7)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I thought there would be an easier way. To use QImage is working fine.